# Não consigo criar um Formulário do Windows usando o .net core

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net-core

Estou [migrando meu projeto do .net Framework pro .net core.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upVQEUc_KwU)

Instalei o Visual Studio Community 2019 e pacotes do .net core (Inclusive do .net core 3.0).

Mas não consigo criar um formulário do  windows com o .net core. Ao tentar tenho essa mensagem de erro :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já segui as orientações descritas mas a seleção que sou orientado a fazer simplesmente não existe no Visual Studio Community 2019:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz no 2017, mas o problema não foi  solucionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Tentei também criar o formulário através do comando :

> dotnet new winforms -o FormularioCore

O projeto é criado, mas não consigo abri-lo. Tenho a mensagem de erro:

> O arquivo do projeto está incompleto. As importações esperadas estão ausentes

Já tentei também reinstalar o Visual Studio Community 2019. O problema persiste.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com a solução desse problema, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução estava em ir Feramentas -> Opções -> Versão Pervia Dos Recursos -> Usar Versão previa do SDK do .Net core.